# Rails routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I've just started learning rails and been going through some tutorials from learning rails (http://www.buildingwebapps.com/podcasts/79335-putting-the-page-contents-into-the)

The tutorials appear to be Rails v2 and I'm on Rails v3

There is a line in the routes file which appears to be causing a problem

```
map.view_page ':name', :controller => 'viewer', :action => 'show'
```

The line works for the front end view i.e. my viewer controller but not for the back end

I get the error

```
NoMethodError in Viewer#show
```

I think this has something to do with the view I am using and the line

```
<%= @page.body %>
```

I know it's difficult without the full code but if anyone can help  that would be awesome

Comment: 1.) In rails 3, we don't use `map.`; 2.) Please check if `@page` is nil or give more concise error message.

Answer (score 1):

The proper route for rails 3 should be

```
match ':name' => 'viewer#show', :as => :view_page
```

Comment: it would be convention to name the controller 'viewers' and thus if you are following a tutorial and there is a viewers controller it should be `viewers#show` but from the code you provided @polarblau is correct.

Comment: Yep. Your usage of Rails in this case is a little unconventional in a few ways :D .

Answer (score 0):

Any tutorials for Rails 2 will likely not fully work in Rails 3.  I think you're setting yourself up to be very confused.

For instance, the line you pasted from `routes.rb` is not Rails 3 compatible.  It should be:

`match ':name' => 'viewer#show', :as => :view_page`

I recommend you start with one of these tutorials, all of which use Rails 3:

- [Ruby on Rails Official Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)
- [Ruby on Rails Tutorial: Learn Rails by Example](http://railstutorial.org)
- [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org)